# integrating chat application with asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chat, livechat

I need to integrate a chat application with my asp.net mvc (C#) application. The users of my application should be able to chat among them after accepting the invitations as like google talk

Any best source for the integration of chat application?

Answer (score 2):

You could most likely make [Chat v1.0](http://chat.codeplex.com/) work in an ASP.Net MVC Site.

Comment: I need to allow the users to be communicated only if they accept the formal chat invitation as google chat.